# Get count of child views?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout which includes x amount of LinearLayouts (children) and a bunch of other views such as TextViews, Relative views etc..

How does one return the amount of children LinearLayout views only?

Comment: use getChildCount, iterate through that and use view instanceof LinearLayout to get only children that are LinearLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would use `ViewGroup.getChildCount()`, but since you want only the count of LinearLayouts you would need to create an algorithm to do so:

```
public int linearLayoutChildCount(ViewGroup parent) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < parent.getChildCount(); x++) {
        if (parent.getChildAt(x) instanceof LinearLayout) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Of course, doing something like this is not ideal since it uses reflection which can be slow on Android.

Comment: @andrew `instanceof` is the reflection I'm referring to, since you are determining the type of an object at runtime.